# c++ pointer to member functions inside the same class

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I have the following:

```
class A {
     typedef void(A::*Exec)(); //this is for creating a pointer to a void the recives void
     void Method(Exec exec)    //Here i have 1 void that recives void parameter
     {
          exec();  
     }
     void SingleProcedure()
     {
          /* code here */
     }
public:
     void Init()
     {
         //Call void method indirectly
         Method(&A::SingleProcedure()); 
         //I don't know how to do the above thing
     }
}
```

So, shortly speaking. I need to have a lot of "void funct()" methods called in the same class by methods.
How do i call a method pointer inside the same class?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The actual snippet has too many syntax errors starting from the first line. When you fix the other syntax errors, gcc will show the hint how to fix the call. `Method1()` does not pass the method, it calls the method.

Comment: Why do so many people call a function that returns `void` "a void" as if it's something special? Would you also call a function returning `double` "a double" or a function returning a custom `goo` type "a goo"? A function is not its return value, it is simply "a function returning <whatever>".  I don't get it.

Comment: You are trying to call a function `exec()` but there's no such function in the code you show.

Comment: Remove the `()` after `&A::SingleProcedure`.

Comment: Still missing semicolon after the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the working example, just don't want to send the OP to read books.

```
class A {
     typedef void(A::*Exec)(); //this is for creating a pointer to a void the recives void
     void Method(Exec exec)    //Here i have 1 void that recives void parameter
     {
          (this->*exec)();  
     }
     void SingleProcedure()
     {
          /* code here */
     }
public:
     void Init()
     {
         //Call void method indirectly
         Method(&A::SingleProcedure); 
         //I don't know how to do the above thing
     }
};
```

Comment: Ok, your (this->*exec)() worked. I figured out using the syntax (*this.*exec)() also works. It seems it's the same thing, dereferencing "this"